# Angular | How to add condition to multiple elements by writing once

Tags: angular

I have a div with multiple buttons in it... All buttons work similarly and I would like to disable all the buttons when a condition is true.

Currently the way I do it is..

```
  <button mat-button [disabled]="isLoading"> X </button>
  <button mat-button [disabled]="isLoading"> Y </button>
  <button mat-button [disabled]="isLoading"> Z </button>
```

Is there a way where I would have to type `[disabled]="isLoading"` only once.

Something like this ***(Doesn't Work)***

```
<ng-container [disabled]="isLoading">
  <button mat-button>X</button>
  <button mat-button>Y</button>
  <button mat-button>Z</button>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: You could do an *ngFor and have an array with your button text, or button objects  in the component then just have the *ngFor repeat each button. If each button would need its unique function call I'm not sure how that would work out with the *ngFor situation. You may have to come up with a unique solution. Depending how many buttons there will actually be, the first example isn't terrible by any means.

Comment: Create a directive use that instead of ng-container. Use `ContentChildren` to list buttons and based on input received add/remove disabled attribute for each button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fieldset` HTML element to group several controls.

```
<fieldset [disabled]="isLoading">
  <button mat-button>X</button>
  <button mat-button>Y</button>
  <button mat-button>Z</button>
</fieldset>
```